# MVC login from parent site to sub-domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, forms-authentication

I have an MVC application that will be deployed to multiple sub-domains, one for each customer, for example customer1.system.mydomain.co.uk, customer2.system.mydomain.co.uk. All of these applications will have their own database with user records.

I want to be able to have a central login application for example login.mydomain.co.uk where customers can go to login and it will redirect them off to their application and they will be logged in, obviously they should not be able to access any other customers applications.

I was planning to have another database to keep all the user details that would be keep in sync with each applications set of users (i.e. when a user adds/updates a user in there application it would also update in the central user database), the central user database would also have details of what application they were for so it would know where to log them in to and redirect them to.

My question is how would I get the central login application to log them in only to their sub-domain and redirect them?

Is this actually possible or is there a better way of doing this?

They would also have to be logged in to the login application itself because if they were to navigate back to the login.mydomain.co.uk and they were already logged in it would have to redirect them straight to their application domain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your plan is for the login application, but I'd do something like this:

Add your users into groups.

Groups have an authenticated redirect url assigned to them, and when a user of a particular group logs in successfully, the website redirects the user to the intended subdomain. The added bonus of this is that if they go back to login.mydomain.co.uk, it should automatically push them onto the subdomain again if their session is still active.

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I want to do but how do I get it so that it only logs them into their URL so that someone can't login to the login application and then get to someone else's application and see their data if they were to know the URL?

Comment: One option could be to return something like an auth token from the login application, which is stored in a cookie and then read by the subdomain website - the contents could be cross-verified by a server request to kick those users who aren't allowed access back to the login site which would bounce them to their own subdomain site. Alternatively, you could have the subdomain query the login application (perhaps query an endpoint?) to validate the current user.

Comment: Do you or anyone else have any code examples of how this might work using C# MVC?

Comment: What about if I made it so that the login cookie was for all the sub-domains, but I created an override on OnActionExecuting for each application that checked the current logged in user has access to the application they are on and if not it would redirect them to the login site? So a user would login on the login site and be redirected to their sub-domain but if they tried to then access someone else's sub-domain the OnActionExecuting method would fire and redirect them back to the login website.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. You could have an endpoint on your MVC application (for the subdomain) which accepts something from the cookie and verifies it against the logged-in user. That could also assist in tracking who is trying to access things they shouldn't be doing :)